# How to know that equivalence is valid?

Tags: logic

Lets denote S(x)-> x is smart and H(x,y) -> x hugs y.

```
∀x[∃y[S(y) ^ ¬H(x; y)]] <-->∀x[¬∀y[¬S(y)^¬H(x; y)]]
```

In my opinion, LHS translates as: "Somebody is smart and everyone does not hug someone" while RHS: " Not everyone is not smart and everyone does not hug not everyone"
I think that LHS implies RHS and I proved it using natural deduction. However, I think that RHS does not imply LHS, but I need counterexample for that for which RHS would be true and LHS false. Can anyone help me how to provide counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

You are right that the LHS implies the RHS

The LHS says that for everyone you can find someone that is smart and not hugged by the first person.

By pushing the negation inside, and applying DeMorgan, the RHS is equivalent to:

$$\forall x \exists y (S(y) \lor H(x,y))$$

So, since the LHS guarantees we can find someone smart for every person, the disjunctin of the RHS will thereby become true as well.

To see that the RHS does not imply the LHS, use:

Domain: a,b

Smart: no one

Hugs: a hugs b and b hugs a

Answer (score 1):

Imagine nobody is smart, but everyone has someone that they hug. In that case, LHS does not hold and RHS does.

Comment: Sorry, but I get why LHS does not hold, but I do not get how RHS holds...

Comment: How nobody is smart is true for RHS?

Comment: It would be very good if you provide with some constants

Comment: Sorry, logged on just now to MSE and saw that @Bram28 has provided a more detailed answer, which gives you an example.